# Rainmeter Meter not hiding

Tags: rainmeter

I am making a rainmeter skin based of the "Elegant Clock" skin, and am trying to make it so that some of the meters will hide if it is before or after a certain time of day. For now, all I want it to do is change what it says in the text. So far (looking at MeasureCalc3 and MeterTime10011) I have this:

```
;Elegant
;Clock Skin - Black
;Created by TwistLemon

[Rainmeter]
Author=TwistLemon
Update=100

[Metadata]
Name=
Author=
Information=
License=
Version=

[Variables]
Size1=74
Size2=18
ClockSize=150
WhiteHands=255,255,255,255
BlackHands=0,0,0,250

;Start time (24-hour clock)
Hour=7
Minute=30
Second=0

;Total number of hours/minutes/seconds
HoursTotal=7
MinutesTotal=20
SecondsTotal=0

;Start time2 (24-hour clock)
Hour2=7
Minute2=30
Second2=0

;Total number of hours/minutes/seconds2
HoursTotal2=2
MinutesTotal2=15
SecondsTotal2=0

;Start time3 (24-hour clock)
Hour3=9
Minute3=45
Second3=0

;Total number of hours/minutes/seconds3
HoursTotal3=1
MinutesTotal3=55
SecondsTotal3=0

;Start time4 (24-hour clock)
Hour4=11
Minute4=40
Second4=0

;Total number of hours/minutes/seconds4
HoursTotal4=3
MinutesTotal4=10
SecondsTotal4=0

;-----------MEASURES------------

[MeasureTime0]
Measure=Time
Format=%H

[MeasureTime1X]
Measure=Time
Format=%I
Substitute="01":"185r","02":"185r","03":"185r","04":"185r","05":"185r","06":"185r","07":"185r","08":"185r","09":"185r","10":"215r","11":"21

5r","12":"215r"

[MeasureTime1]
Measure=Time
Format=%I
Substitute="01":"1:","02":"2:","03":"3:","04":"4:","05":"5:","06":"6:","07":"7:","08":"8:","09":"9:","10":"10:","11":"11:","12":"12:"

[MeasureTime2]
Measure=Time
Format=%M %p

[MeasureTime3]
Measure=Time
Format=%M 

[MeasureDate]
Measure=Time
Format=%A, %d %B %Y

[MeasureDate2]
Measure=Time
Format=%d
Substitute="01":"1","02":"2","03":"3","04":"4","05":"5","06":"6","07":"7","08":"8","09":"9"

[MeasureDate3]
Measure=Time
Format=%m

[MeasureDate4]
Measure=Time
Format=%Y

[MeasureFull]
Measure=calc
Formula=1

[MeasureSeconds]
Measure=TIME
Format=%S
Substitute="00":"0","01":"1","02":"2","03":"3","04":"4","05":"5","06":"6","07":"7","08":"8","09":"9"

[MeasureSeconds2]
Measure=TIME
Format=%S

[MeasureCalc]
Measure=calc
Formula=(MeasureSeconds2/60)

[MeasureFull]
Measure=calc
Formula=1

[MeasureCalc2]
Measure=calc
Formula=((((#HoursTotal#*3600)+#MinutesTotal#*60)+#SecondsTotal#)-(((((((MeasureTime0-#Hour#)*60)+MeasureTime3)-

#Minute#)*60)+(MeasureSeconds-#Second#))/((((#HoursTotal#*3600)+#MinutesTotal#*60)+#SecondsTotal#))*

(((#HoursTotal#*3600)+#MinutesTotal#*60)+#SecondsTotal#)))

[MeasureCalc3]
Measure=calc
Formula=((((#HoursTotal2#*3600)+#MinutesTotal2#*60)+#SecondsTotal2#)-(((((((MeasureTime0-#Hour2#)*60)+MeasureTime3)-

#Minute2#)*60)+(MeasureSeconds-#Second2#))/((((#HoursTotal2#*3600)+#MinutesTotal2#*60)+#SecondsTotal2#))*

(((#HoursTotal2#*3600)+#MinutesTotal2#*60)+#SecondsTotal2#)))
IfConditionMode=1
IfCondition=((((((#HoursTotal#*3600)+#MinutesTotal#*60)+#SecondsTotal#)-(((((((MeasureTime0-#Hour#)*60)+MeasureTime3)-

#Minute#)*60)+(MeasureSeconds-#Second#))/((((#HoursTotal#*3600)+#MinutesTotal#*60)+#SecondsTotal#))*

(((#HoursTotal#*3600)+#MinutesTotal#*60)+#SecondsTotal#))))>(18300))
IfTrueAction=!SetOption MeasureCalc3 Formula hi
IfFalseAction=!SetOption MeasureCalc3 Formula no

[MeasureCalc4]
Measure=calc
Formula=((((#HoursTotal3#*3600)+#MinutesTotal3#*60)+#SecondsTotal3#)-(((((((MeasureTime0-#Hour3#)*60)+MeasureTime3)-

#Minute3#)*60)+(MeasureSeconds-#Second3#))/((((#HoursTotal3#*3600)+#MinutesTotal3#*60)+#SecondsTotal3#))*

(((#HoursTotal3#*3600)+#MinutesTotal3#*60)+#SecondsTotal3#)))

[MeasureCalc5]
Measure=calc
Formula=((((#HoursTotal4#*3600)+#MinutesTotal4#*60)+#SecondsTotal4#)-(((((((MeasureTime0-#Hour4#)*60)+MeasureTime3)-

#Minute4#)*60)+(MeasureSeconds-#Second4#))/((((#HoursTotal4#*3600)+#MinutesTotal4#*60)+#SecondsTotal4#))*

(((#HoursTotal4#*3600)+#MinutesTotal4#*60)+#SecondsTotal4#)))


;-----------METERS------------

[MeterTime1
MeasureName=MeasureSeconds
Meter=STRING
X=56
Y=1
FontColor=000000
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime111]
MeasureName=MeasureSeconds
Meter=STRING
X=52
Y=-4
FontColor=000000
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime15]
MeasureName=MeasureSeconds
Meter=STRING
X=54
Y=0
FontColor=2BB4D6
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime2215]
MeasureName=MeasureSeconds
Meter=STRING
X=54
Y=0
FontColor=2BB4D6
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime115]
MeasureName=MeasureSeconds
Meter=STRING
X=53
Y=-2
FontColor=FFFFFFF
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterBar42]
Meter=BAR
MeasureName=MeasureCalc
Flip=1
BarOrientation=Horizontal
X=5
Y=118
H=5
W=57
BarColor=000000

[MeterBar32]
Meter=BAR
MeasureName=MeasureCalc
Flip=1
BarOrientation=Horizontal
X=4
Y=117
H=5
W=57
BarColor=2BB4D6

[MeterBar22]
Meter=BAR
MeasureName=MeasureCalc
Flip=1
BarOrientation=Horizontal
X=2
Y=113
H=5
W=57
BarColor=000000

[MeterBar12]
Meter=BAR
MeasureName=MeasureCalc
Flip=1
BarOrientation=Horizontal
X=3
Y=115
H=5
W=57
BarColor=FFFFFF

[MeterBar4]
Meter=BAR
MeasureName=MeasureCalc
BarOrientation=Horizontal
X=58
Y=118
H=5
W=58
BarColor=000000

[MeterBar3]
Meter=BAR
MeasureName=MeasureCalc
BarOrientation=Horizontal
X=57
Y=117
H=5
W=58
BarColor=2BB4D6

[MeterBar2]
Meter=BAR
MeasureName=MeasureCalc
BarOrientation=Horizontal
X=56
Y=113
H=5
W=58
BarColor=000000

[MeterBar1]
Meter=BAR
MeasureName=MeasureCalc
BarOrientation=Horizontal
X=56
Y=115
H=5
W=58
BarColor=FFFFFF

[MeterBarTotal]
Meter=BAR
MeasureName=MeasureFull
X=-20
Y=0
H=115
W=99999
BarColor=185,250,160,2
SolidColor=150,150,150,2

[MeterTime100]
MeasureName=MeasureCalc2
Meter=STRING
X=506
Y=1
FontColor=000000
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime11100]
MeasureName=MeasureCalc2
Meter=STRING
X=502
Y=-4
FontColor=000000
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime1500]
MeasureName=MeasureCalc2
Meter=STRING
X=504
Y=0
FontColor=2BB4D6
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime11500]
MeasureName=MeasureCalc2
Meter=STRING
X=503
Y=-2
FontColor=FFFFFFF
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime10011]
MeasureName=MeasureCalc3
Text=""
Meter=STRING
X=906
Y=1
FontColor=000000
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime1110011]
MeasureName=MeasureCalc3
Meter=STRING
X=902
Y=-4
FontColor=000000
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime150011]
MeasureName=MeasureCalc3
Meter=STRING
X=904
Y=0
FontColor=2BB4D6
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime1150011]
MeasureName=MeasureCalc3
Meter=STRING
X=903
Y=-2
FontColor=FFFFFFF
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime1001122]
MeasureName=MeasureCalc4
Meter=STRING
X=906
Y=1
FontColor=000000
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime111001122]
MeasureName=MeasureCalc4
Meter=STRING
X=902
Y=-4
FontColor=000000
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime15001122]
MeasureName=MeasureCalc4
Meter=STRING
X=904
Y=0
FontColor=2BB4D6
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime115001122]
MeasureName=MeasureCalc4
Meter=STRING
X=903
Y=-2
FontColor=FFFFFFF
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime100112233]
MeasureName=MeasureCalc5
Meter=STRING
X=906
Y=1
FontColor=000000
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime11100112233]
MeasureName=MeasureCalc5
Meter=STRING
X=902
Y=-4
FontColor=000000
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime1500112233]
MeasureName=MeasureCalc5
Meter=STRING
X=904
Y=0
FontColor=2BB4D6
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1

[MeterTime11500112233]
MeasureName=MeasureCalc5
Meter=STRING
X=903
Y=-2
FontColor=FFFFFFF
FontSize=74
FontFace=Antipasto
StringAlign=CENTER
;StringStyle=BOLD
AntiAlias=1
```

What exactly am I doing wrong with the IfCondition statment to where the meter shows the value of the expression rather than the forced "hi" or "no"?

Comment: If you break down your code and only show us the accentual problem, people are more likely to read it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to use the !SetOption bang, why don't you directly use it in your measureCalc3 to set the text of your MeterTime10011?

So do

```
IfTrueAction=!SetOption MeterTime10011 Text hi
IfFalseAction=!SetOption MeterTime10011 Text no
```